# Authenticated user making AJAX requests to rails API from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, devise

I'm building a Rails app and I'm using Devise for authentication.
When the user is logged in I need to make an AJAX call to Rails and get data that belongs to the current user as JSON. Also I don't want unauthenticated users and other logged-in users to access the current user's resources.

I'm using jQuery's $.getJSON() to make the AJAX request by simply specifying the link address like this:

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/users/1/photos', function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

So far authetication seems to work in the same manner it worked for the HTTP requests therefore a user can access only his own data via AJAX.

I don't have too much experience with AJAX and I don't understand why this **does** work at all. From where does my rails app know that I'm logged in when I make the AJAX call? I thought I had to create an extra authentication token and use it for authentication or to set the devise session cookie when performing the AJAX call.

Later Edit: From where does my rails app know that I'm logged in when I make the AJAX call?

Comment: An ajax request is also an HTTP request and  the server wouldn't necessarily know or care if a request is ajax or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An AJAX request (XMLHttpRequest) will contain the same headers at a standard HTTP request for the same domain. As far as reading the cookie from the header, looking up the session information, and authorizing the request, the behavior will be the same.

Comment: So basically the AJAX request sends the cookie too and that's the reason it works. That's cool. I thought it doesn't.

Comment: Now I wonder if there are any other security issues with this aproach. Do I need to send a CSRF token or something else with the request?

Comment: There is no appreciable difference between the two types of requests from a security perspective as long as they are both on the same domain.